# How does a 24 bit number overflow into a 32 bit type?

Tags: c

If I pack three unsigned chars into a 32 bit integer, and the most significant byte overflows, does it spill into the upper 8 bits of the 32 bit type? Does it just reduce the MSB by modulo 256 not affecting the upper 8 bits of the 32 bit type?

EDIT:

```
Packed using bit shifting on little endian architecture: 

unsigned int foo = (msb << 16) | (middle << 8) | lsb;
```

Comment: Depends on how you packed the chars into the integer, how the most significant byte overflowed, and what the endianness is.

Comment: The line of code you showed might suffer sign-extension, but not overflow.  What operation are you thinking might overflow?

Comment: The only way "overflow" is possible is if `CHAR_BIT >= 16`.

Comment: How could it overflow during this operation? The only thing that could happen is sign extension which is prevented by using the `unsigned char` type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your variable is a 32-bit type which happens to contain a 24-bit value, overflow of the 24-bit part will move up into the 25th bit.  So it will behave as a normal 32-bit value.

For example:

```
uint32_t x = 0xFFFFFF;
printf("x=%08x\n", x);   // prints 00FFFFFF
x++;
printf("x=%08x\n", x);   // prints 01000000
```

Comment: Is there anywhere that explains this behavior in general? For other types as well.

Comment: Probably in the [C standards](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf).  In general though, it doesn't matter if you treat an integer variable of one type as a smaller type.  The carryover rules of the actual type of the variable are what matters.